# C# populating 2 combo boxes and 1 text box with values from a txt file with only 1 selection

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox, text-files

I have a text file which has 3 "columns" separated by commas,

I can load these in to each combobox or text box individually

What I want to do is select only the first columns value from the `nameComboBox`, then the other 2 boxes are populated automatically with the values from the same row.

Also if i can improve the way I put the last column into a combobox then into a text box.

Also thinking about it, I can change both `numberComboBox` & `descriptionComboBox` to text boxes as they wont be being select from?

Text file (`notes.txt`) :

```
run, 1, runs the file
save, 2, saves the file
delete, 3, deletes the file
```

Current code:

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] notes = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\notes.txt");
        foreach (var line in notes)
        {
            string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
            nameComboBox.Items.Add(tokens[0]);
            numberComboBox.Items.Add(tokens[1]);
            descriptionComboBox.Items.Add(tokens[2]);
        }

        descriptionComboBox.Text = descriptionTextBox.Text;
    }
```

So for example if I select `run` from the `nameComboBox` I want the `numberComboBox` to be populated with `2` and the `descriptionComboBox` to be populated with `deletes the file`.

Better yetI select `run` from the `nameComboBox` I want the `numberTextBox` to be populated with `2` and the `descriptionTextBox` to be populated with `deletes the file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the SelectedIndexChanged event of your Combobox:

```
private void nameComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
          numberComboBox.SelectedIndex = descriptionComboBox.SelectedIndex = nameComboBox.SelectedIndex;
}
```

You must associate the eventhandler beforehand:

```
this.nameComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += 
        new System.EventHandler(nameComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: This works great, didn't need to associate the eventhandler.